# Julia : Initiliase a vector of an array of vectors

Tags: arrays, vector, julia

So I defined:

```
v =Array{Vector{Int64}, 5}
```

Now I want `v[1]` to be the empty vector.
I tried:
`v[1] = Int64[]` ,
`v[1]=Vector{Int64}()`
It does not work.
How can I access this vector and fill it with a value?

Comment: Somehow I feel you want: `v = Vector{Vector{Int}}(undef, 5)` and then `v[1] = Int64[]` works. (this is called a vector of vectors. Array is the generic name for all tensors: vectors, matrices, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `v = Array{Vector{Int64}, 5}` is a type not an instance. You can use some of these options:

```
julia> v = Vector{Vector{Int}}(undef,5);

julia> v[1] = Int[];

julia> v[2] = [1,2,3];

julia> v
5-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
    []
    [1, 2, 3]
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

Or if you don't mind starting with empty vectors, this can be simpler:

```
julia> v = [Int[] for i=1:5];

julia> v[2] = [1,2,3];

julia> v
5-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 []
 [1, 2, 3]
 []
 []
 []
```

Comment: instead of undef can we initiliase the vectors to be emty? ```v = Vector{Vector{Int}}(Int[],5)``` did not work

Comment: You can use my second method above, or simply `v = fill(Int[],5)`.

Answer (score 2):

You want `v =Array{Vector{Int64}, 5}(undef, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)` (where the `s`s are the size of each dimension) otherwise, `v` is the type, not an object of that type.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the actual goal is not a rank 5 array... nevertheless, this is literally correct.